# Running Into A Contradiction In Algebra/Category Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

In Aluffi's Algebra Chapter 0, on page 34, he proves the following claim:

*Claim 5.5: Denoting by $\pi$ the 'canonical projection' defined in Example 2.6 [he means $\pi:A \rightarrow A/\sim$ for some equivalencce relation $\sim$] the pair $(\pi, A/\sim)$ is an initial object of this category.*

More precisely he means that if $\phi:A \rightarrow Z$ is a morphism that there exists a unique function $\bar{\phi}$ such that $\bar{\phi}\pi = \phi$.  However, I am having trouble conceptualizing this.

In particular, I am thinking of the example in which $Z = A$.  Clearly, $1_A:A \rightarrow A$ exists as long as $A$ is non-empty.  Also, a surjective canoncial projection $\pi:A \rightarrow A/\sim$ exists for any equivalence relation $\sim$ on $A$.

My problem then, is that the above theorem states that there exists some unique function $\bar{1_A}$ such that $\bar{1_A}\pi = 1_A$.  However, this appears to imply that canonical projections have left-inverses, meaning they are injective!!  This is obviously not true.

What mistake am I making??

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quotient $(\pi,A/\sim)$ is an initial object, not of the category whose objects are arbitrary maps out of $A$, but of the category whose objects are maps out of $A$ *which identify elements of $A$ equivalent under $\sim$*. So $1_A$ is an object in the relevant category if and only if $\sim$ is the discrete relation, in which case $\pi=1_A$ and there's no problem.

Comment: Thanks! I had been tacitly assuming there were no preconditions on $\phi$.  Embarassing!!! I'll check mark your answer in 5 minutes when stackexchange allows me to.